# Pandas ffill for certain values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
time     data
0         1
1         1
2         nan
3         nan
4         6
5         nan
6         nan
7         nan
8         5
9         4
10        nan
```

Is there a way to use `pd.Series.ffill()` to ffill on for certain occurences of values? Specifically, I want to forward fill only if values in `df.data` are == 1 or 4. Should look like this:

```
time     data
0         1
1         1
2         1
3         1
4         6
5         nan
6         nan
7         nan
8         5
9         4
10        4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to forward fill ([`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html)) the column, then only populate where the values are `1` or `4` using ([`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)) and ([`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)):

```
s = df['data'].ffill()
df['data'] = df['data'].mask(s.isin([1, 4]), s)
```

`df`:

```
    time  data
0      0   1.0
1      1   1.0
2      2   1.0
3      3   1.0
4      4   6.0
5      5   NaN
6      6   NaN
7      7   NaN
8      8   5.0
9      9   4.0
10    10   4.0
```